# document.domain is the same yet still getting same-origin errors

Tags: javascript, cors, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have some javascript that looks like this:

```
// https://secure.example.com
document.domain = "example.com";
window.myVar = "value";

// http://example.com
document.domain = "example.com";
var iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("iframe"));
iframe.onload = function () {
    console.log(iframe.contentWindow.myVar);
}
iframe.src = "https://secure.example.com";
```

I'm trying to access `myVar` from `https://secure.example.com` by loading it into an iframe in `http://example.com`. Note the usage of `http` and `https`. When both domains used `http` or `https` this worked, but now I would like to have one use `http` and the other to use `https`. I've stepped through the code to verify that `document.domain` is set correctly. Why is this happening?

Comment: http and https are NOT the same origin, just like example.com:80 is NOT the same origin as example.com:8080. There are VERY good reasons to not be allowed to mix http and https

Comment: Apparently that is the case, but I can't find any information about how setting `document.domain` does or does not affect the protocol check.

Comment: It is irrelevant You cannot use document.domain across protocols  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: _"but I can't find any information about how setting document.domain does or does not affect the protocol check"_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain: "Gets/sets **the domain portion** of the origin of the current document"

Comment: In the doc for Same Origin Policy, they refer to host/port/protocol. It never equates domain and host. I guess that is the source of the confusion.

Comment: Your issue is not domain or host. Your issue is protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not domain or host. Your issue is protocol

You cannot set `document.domain` across protocols

`http` and `https` are NOT the same origin due to protocol, just like example.com:80 is NOT the same origin as example.com:8080 due to ports.

There are VERY good security reasons to not be allowed to mix http and https

Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

Based on MDN's page [How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content):

> The best strategy to avoid mixed content blocking is to serve all the
>   content as HTTPS instead of HTTP.
>
> For your own domain, serve all content as HTTPS and fix your links. 
>   Often, the HTTPS version of the content already exists and this just
>   requires adding an "s" to links - http:// to https://.
>
> For other domains, use the site's HTTPS version if available. If HTTPS
>   is not available, you can try contacting the domain and asking them if
>   they can make the content available via HTTPS.